# How reduce APK size?

Tags: android, apk

I have 20 .mp3  file in my app , the size of **APK** is about 50 MB , is there  any  solution to reduce the .mp3 size but quality did not change?

I use *proguard*  and  *shrinkResources* but they do not  have  any remarkable effect.

Comment: Are these mp3s contain music/sound effects or verbal messages?

Comment: those are music

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

1. Convert your MP3 files to **M4A format**
2. Go to **Android Studio Menu > Refactor > Remove Unused Resources**
3. Enable the **Proguard** and set `shrinkResources` to **true**
4. Use **Android App Bundle** instead of APK

Answer (score 0):

You should use android apple bundle, it is way more efficient than APK files. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Comment: The bundle will help if he's putting out an APK built for multiple architectures but I think (at least he believes) that the bulk is due to the mp3 resources. One suggestion might be to include a minimum number of mp3s and fetch the rest dynamically as needed. Either way, going to the AAB is what google wants us to do and makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

You should android app bundle and then in the build.gradle go find proguard minifyEnabled and make it true that will also help decrease the size of your app and will remove extra code and enable shrinkResources to reduce the APK size by shrinking resources